# Integrate Gaussian over elliptic area

Tags: integration, surfaces, gaussian-integral

I have got a two-dimensional gaussian distribution, where $\sigma_x = \sigma_y$ and $\mu_x = \mu_y = 0$.

$$ f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi \sigma^2} e ^{-\left( \frac{x^2 + y^2}{2\sigma^2} 
\right)}$$

I would like to know the integral over this function. I'm basically looking for the $2$D     analog  of the error function. The area I want to integrate over is an ellipse centered around zeros.

$$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} \leq 1$$

How do I get an analytical solution to this problem?

Comment: there is an answer on MathOverflow, https://mathoverflow.net/a/292954/11260